# Is it possible to safely edit mysql-bin.index file while mysql server is running

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb

I changed location of mysql bin-log files. I copied them so mysql started fine, because they where in both locations, but then removed them from old location. I forget about correcting the path in index file and now I have problems with purging old binary logs.

So my question is it safe to correct paths in index file while mysql server is running

For example `cat correct.index > mysql-bin.index`

My server version is mariadb 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a supported procedure as highlighted in official MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html):

> To keep track of which binary log files have been used, mysqld also
>   creates a binary log index file that contains the names of all used
>   binary log files. By default, this has the same basename as the binary
>   log file, with the extension '.index'. You can change the name of the
>   binary log index file with the --log-bin-index[=file_name] option. You
>   should not manually edit this file while mysqld is running; doing so
>   would confuse mysqld.

So no, it's not safe to edit binary log index while `mysqld` is running.